# How can I send an array between different .swift files in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2

There is one two-dimension array in my `viewcontrollerOne`.

```
var estRent = [
            ("Weekly Rent:", a),
            ("Monthly Rent:", b),
            ("Yearly Rent:", c),
               ]
```

The first dimension is constants and the second one is variables. I declare it in an `ButtonAction` function. I want to give the variables value and pass the whole array to another .`swift` file when I click the button. I already know how to jump from the `viewcontroller` via button.

But how to send the array to the .swift in the same time?

Comment: You mean you want to send that array to another swift file ( viewController? ) when you change the page?

Comment: read about prepareForSegue

Comment: That is probably what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object

Comment: I mean I want to send the array from one swift file to another swift file when I click a button. The button action will change the viewcontroller. I want to use the array in the second swift file.

Comment: When you pushing with the help of Segue, need to pass data to second class variables or use there Model class. Need to learn about  model class pattern and Navigation pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an Array variable on `SecondViewController` & pass the value on button action like this -

```
var secondvc = SecondViewController();
secondvc.yourArray = estRent;
```

That's all.

Comment: Hi, how to declare an array[String,String] in secondViewController?

Answer (score 0):

The first view controller that contains the array:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var estRent = [ ("Weekly Rent:", 512), ("Monthly Rent:", 1024), ("Yearly Rent:", 12120)]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let viewController = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
      viewController.estRent = estRent
    }
  }

}
```

In second view controller that you are planning to send the array to:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

  var estRent = [(String, Int)]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(estRent)
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi, In the "viewController.array = self.estRent", there is an error said "cannot assign value of type [(String,String)] to type [Any]"

Comment: I also tried to just send the array[String], but there is an error in navigationController.topViewController, and if I use segue.destinationViewController, there is an error in self.estRent