# iOS Segue PopOver How To Back Pass Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uipopover

[image]
i want send data view controller (left) from PopOverController (Right), how can I do it?

Comment: you need to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object.

Comment: But i want to back in data (left) not send to popoverController. popoverController to send View Controller, i use [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: ok then you need to use custom delegates.

Comment: Most probably `dismissViewControllerAnimated` used when you navigate your app using `presentViewCont` method now here you need to use `popViewControllerAnimated` method in this case, there are certain no of methods to navigate app to diff VC.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data in prepareForSegue method, but first add identifier for segue.
And use this code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPopover"]) {
            NSLog(@"FirstViewController: prepareForSegue");
            PopOverController * popoverVC = segue.destinationViewController;
            popoverVC.myProperty = @"Data to be passed";
        }
    }
```

Comment: i use [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; because of that prepareForSegue not working

Comment: where you use [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; ?

Comment: prepareForSegue method called when ever you press the button in your case.
can you please show me your code ?

Comment: it's okay to use dismiss method in that view controller, but if you are doing that in correct way then prepareForSegue must called.

Answer (score 0):

First make one property which you get data of another viewcontroller .

In you case assume we want String data to first viewController so we make one property in second means PopOverController

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *recipeName;
```

After call prepare for segue method in first viewController in your case ViewController

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"IdentifierOfPushViewController"]) {
        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipeName = @"Hello this passing data"
    }
}
```