# Pass NSMutableDictionary from one view to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, copy, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to pass data from one ViewController to another ViewController.

Firstviewcontroller.m

```
-(void)NavigateToAnotherScreen:(NSMutableDictionary*)dict{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NavDashBoardToInfo" sender:self];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"NavDashBoardToInfo"])
    {
        InfoViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [vc setAppointmentDictionary:dict];
    }
}
```

Secondviewcontroller.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *AppointmentDictionary;
```

Secondviewcontroller.m

```
@synthesize AppointmentDictionary;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"dict===>%@",AppointmentDictionary); // This gives me null
}
```

Please help me. What i am doing wrong.

I am getting `AppointmentDictionary = (null)` in `viewwillappear`.
Though I am doing proper copy of this.

Comment: This has been asked several times, did you look at available SO Posts?

Comment: So many wrong things here, how you initialize vc is wrong, and you dont need to init it to call segue, you have to pass the data from `prepareForSegue`, and last thing is the function and property name should be in lowercase

Comment: @Tj3n thank you for the comment. I will change the property and function name. have to pass data from prepareForSegue ? I didnot understand.

Comment: Read http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Comment: Check here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setAppointmentDictionary:)]) {
    [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setAppointmentDictionary:)
                                          withObject:dict];
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this one:**

```
-(void)NavigateToAnotherScreen:(NSMutableDictionary*)dict
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NavDashBoardToInfo" sender:dict];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
         InfoViewController *info = segue.destinationViewController;
         info.AppointmentDictionary = sender;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating  InfoViewController instance and not pushing that view controller. You doing a "performSegueWithIdentifier" here new instance will  create, so you first instance "info" is not passing here. You can do in other way.

```
 InfoViewController *info = [[InfoViewController alloc] init];
 info.AppointmentDictionary = [dict mutableCopy];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController: info animated:true];
```

Option 2:

```
-(void)NavigateToAnotherScreen:(NSMutableDictionary*)dict{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NavDashBoardToInfo" sender: [dict mutableCopy]];

}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"NavDashBoardToInfo"]) {
        InfoViewController *viewController = (InfoViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.AppointmentDictionary = (NSMutableDictionary *)sender;
    }
}
```

In the prepareforsegue method you have to pass the value like mentioned above.
Note: make sure your destination view controller is InfoViewController

Comment: `[[InfoViewController alloc] init];` this will result in blank viewcontroller, I think rather point him to use segue is better

Comment: Updated the answer have a look into this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `performsegue` for navigation then you can use below method for transferring data between ViewControllers

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"NavDashBoardToInfo"])
    {
        InfoViewController *info = [segue destinationViewController];
        info.AppointmentDictionary = "Value you want to pass";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using performSegueWithIdentifier then provide the body in function . Don't create any new instance using code and provide segue in storyboard -

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourController_Segue"]) {
        YourController *viewController = (YourController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.AppointmentDictionary = (NSMutableDictionary *)sender;
    }
}
```