# Swift : Data passed through unwind segue is erased before being read

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, date, segue

I try to pass a Date from a ViewController to another one through an unwind segue. The problem is that the data passed is replaced by the result of *Date()*.

Here is the code of the VC where the date is selected :

```
class DateSelectorViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    ...

    @IBAction func validateDate(_ sender: CustomButton) {
        sendDateToNextVC(sender: sender)
    }   

    func sendDateToNextVC(sender: UIButton) {
        let destinationVC = AddActivityViewController()
        destinationVC.dateSelected = dateSelected
        destinationVC.recurrenceType = selectedFrequency
        destinationVC.isRecurrent = recurrent
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "sendSelectedDate", sender: sender)
    } 
}
```

And here is the code of the VC that receive the date in *dateSelected* :

```
class AddActivityViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    ...    

    var dateSelected: Date = Date()

    ... 

    @IBAction func unwindToAddActiVC(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if sender.identifier == "sendSelectedDate" {
            setDateLabel()
        }
    } 

    func setDateLabel() {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
        dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: dateSelected)
    }

}
```

I remarked that the line

```
var dateSelected: Date = Date()
```

was called multiple times, especially once after that the date was passed from the first VC to the destination VC. I tried using optional but it only leads to obvious errors "*found nil while unwrapping*".

Please let me know if you need other pieces of code.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are instantiated a new **ViewController** and not using the one is the **Segue**

**This part of your code is wrong**

```
func sendDateToNextVC(sender: UIButton) {
        let destinationVC = AddActivityViewController()
        destinationVC.dateSelected = dateSelected
        destinationVC.recurrenceType = selectedFrequency
        destinationVC.isRecurrent = recurrent
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "sendSelectedDate", sender: sender)
    }
```

In fact, your are creating a new viewController, the segue do already the job.

**Use *prepareForSegue* instead:**

```
 @IBAction func validateDate(_ sender: CustomButton) {
        sendDateToNextVC(sender: sender)
    }

    func sendDateToNextVC(sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "sendSelectedDate", sender: sender)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "sendSelectedDate",
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? AddActivityViewController{
            destinationVC.dateSelected = dateSelected
            destinationVC.recurrenceType = selectedFrequency
            destinationVC.isRecurrent = recurrent
        }
    }
```

**Here you will get the viewcontroller used in the segue, your problem should be solved.**

Hope it helps.

Pierre

Comment: While I get the use of headers to add structure to a text, with all due respect in your answer there are more headers than text. Please, try to reduce the use of headers. Imagine if all answers were like this. It would be pretty hard to read. Still, thank you for your answer, it's correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

In your `sendDateToNextVC` method you create a new `AddActivityViewController` instance, and then just throw it away. iOS doesn't know about it, it just creates another instance. You're setting the date to the instance you created, whereas iOS keeps working with an instance of its own.

You should use `prepareForSegue` method to pass the date instead. And not create the VC yourself, but get it from the Segue object inside the `prepareForSegue` method.

It would look something like this:

```
class DateSelectorViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    ...

    @IBAction func validateDate(_ sender: CustomButton) {
        sendDateToNextVC(sender: sender)
    }   

    func sendDateToNextVC(sender: UIButton) {
        let destinationVC = AddActivityViewController()
        destinationVC.dateSelected = dateSelected
        destinationVC.recurrenceType = selectedFrequency
        destinationVC.isRecurrent = recurrent
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "sendSelectedDate", sender: sender)
    } 

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? AddActivityViewController {
            destinationVC.dateSelected = dateSelected
            destinationVC.recurrenceType = selectedFrequency
            destinationVC.isRecurrent = recurrent
        }
    }
}
```

More details here: [SO: How to pass prepareForSegue: an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29550754/1856325)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

DateSelectorViewController must override,

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "sendSelectedDate"{
        var vc = segue.destinationViewController as! AddActivityViewController
        vc.data = "Data you want to pass"
        //Data has to be a variable name in your AddActivityViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !