# Send photo to next screen on button press

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

So I am building a IOS app and i have a photo gallery that shows up, when you press a photo it registers and you can do something with that photo. basically what I need is when a user presses that photo I need it to open up another screen (segue) and I need to know on that new screen what that particular photo that was pressed is and set a screen sized UIViewController as that photo. the code that i currently have is

```
      PhotoEditorViewController *editor = [[PhotoEditorViewController alloc] init];
ALAsset *asset = self.assets[indexPath.row];
ALAssetRepresentation *defaultRep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
editor.img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[defaultRep fullScreenImage] scale:[defaultRep scale] orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
NSLog(@"Photo Pressed");
NSLog(@"%@", editor.img);

[self presentModalViewController:editor animated:YES];
```

so what this currently is doing is getting the photo that is pressd and setting my UIImage var. "img" as that image then when the segue is called i can see on the other screens viewDidLoad method that the image transferred over but for some reason i am unable to set that image as the UIImageViwer.

NSLog output:

On both screen one and screen two is shows UIImage 0x#######

Which makes me believe that the photo ID information is transferring however it’s not updating the uiimageview

```
    ViewDidLoad
        {
             NSLog(@“%hhu%”, editorPhoto);
             [image setImage:editorPhoto];
        }
```

Comment: Please show the PhotoEditorViewController code that is supposed to be "updating the UIImageView" on the "second screen".

Comment: @matt I added the code not home so I only added the important code. So when the code runs it prints the right stuff but if you breakpoint as setImage it shows that the image is null

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'prepare for Segue' method to pass data between ViewControllers:

create a UIImage in PhotoEditorViewController to hold the passed image

```
@IBOutlet weak var passedImage: UIImageView!
```

In your first ViewController

**Swift 3.0**

```
@IBOutlet weak var selectedImage: UIImageView!

override fun prepare(for segue: UIStorybordSegue, sender: Any?) {
      //set destination to PhotoEditorViewController
      if let destination = segue.destination as? 
      PhotoEditorViewController {

      //send image to 'passedImage' in PhotoEditorViewController
      destination.passedImage = selectedImage.image
}
```

**Objectivce-C**

see [How to pass prepareForSegue: an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object)

Comment: How do you do this in objective c

Comment: added link to relevant article

Comment: double check in your project.storyboard that you have created a segue between the view controllers and that you name that segue the exact same as the segue you're trying to call

Answer (score 0):

Create the property in nextViewController.h file.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imgView;
```

---

Pass Image from here.

```
- (IBAction)nextView:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    myViewController *VC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllerID"];
    VC.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];
}
```