# accidentally deleted segue. suggestions?

Tags: ios, xcode, segue, viewcontroller

I had created a segue that performs on my app only if users have entered the correct login information. I accidentally deleted the action. Now when I click my login button, it puts me in the next view controller without putting information into the text fields. I created a new segue and I programmed it into my storyboard with the same title. Is there a possible way to fix this without restarting?

Comment: Implement prepareForSegue in your view controller.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the usual?

- Edit | Undo (this works well in Interface Builder)
- Git

Otherwise, this you'll need to reimplement.

Comment: hello,  I checked the edit undo however it never showed up. I ran the program and after my program crashed, I tried to undo it however it never showed up.

Comment: I will post my code in an answer form, please tell me if it's correct.