# Load Request url in UIWebView of viewcontroller from another viewcontroller navbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Im trying to

```
[webLoad loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

in a ViewController when clicked from AnotherViewController's

```
- (IBAction)actionClick:(id)sender { }
```

navigation icon.

i used below code, but its not working

```
=========================AnotherViewController============================

- (IBAction)actionClick:(id)sender {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Notification" object:self];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toURL" sender:self];
}

=============================ViewController============================

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self                                       
              selector:@selector(Notification:)
              name:@"Notification"
              object:nil];
    }
- (void) Notification:(NSNotification *) notification
{

       progressBar.progress = 0;
       progressBar.hidden = false;
       NSString *urlString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"urlSearch"];
       urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
       [webLoad loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

}
```

Comment: You should visit this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies in this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Notification" object:self];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toURL" sender:self];
```

You post a notification before ViewController is even initialised.
I can't see you are making any use of NSNotification in your code whatsoever.
So if you just want the ViewController to loads a url when opened up then you can just simply do this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self loadUrl];
}
- (void)loadUrl
{
       progressBar.progress = 0;
       progressBar.hidden = false;
       NSString *urlString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"urlSearch"];
       urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
       [webLoad loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you declare a property on your ViewController, i.e.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *urlString;
```

Then pass it on prepare segue as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7865100/1871523).

i.e.

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ViewControllerSegue"]) {
ViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
vc.urlString = @“yourURL”; }
```

Then modify your loadURL to accept string, like so :

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self loadUrl:urlString];
}

- (void)loadUrl:(String *)urlString
{
       progressBar.progress = 0;
       progressBar.hidden = false;
       NSString *encodedString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
       [webLoad loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

}
```