# Show screen after login in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a 2 viewControllers in my storyboards, I am making a login (all with objective C), when the credentials are OK I need to show another screen (and send data if is possible), but I found examples with segues and take the button to do it, I dont want to set the button to the segue because when I push it the another screen will be shown

I need to show the new screen only on the condition "if credentials are ok"

Comment: If i remember you must use something like prepareforseque. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object

Answer (score 0):

You can create a seque, give it some id and then call like this when you need to:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSeque" sender:self];
```

Comment: but it not works because if I define the segue from the button to the next screen, when I push the button automatically will show the screen, and If I define the segue from the view controller to the other viewcontroller does not work, or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: You should define a seque from first view controller to the second, not on the button. Then it will work, just give it the right ID and make sure you call it when needed!

Comment: it works! but, the new screen appear like a modal, so i can drag and close it, is there a way to show the second screen and replace the first one, without posibility to return, please

Comment: you could wrap both into a NavigationController, then it wouldn't appear as a modal

Comment: I did it, in presentation I set "full screen", thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can create login button action manually and try below code.

```
- (IBAction)LoginButtonAction:(id)sender {

    if ([self validated]) {    // check login validation on "validate" method. 

         UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
         HomeVC *home = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVC"];

         UINavigationController *NavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: home];    // for set HomeVC as a root view controller.

         [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:NavigationController];
    }
}
```